# PHP json loop always fill value even on empty result on query

Tags: php, json, loops

I'm working with PHP json loop data.

Here is the code:

```
$qGetAllLine = oci_parse($c1, "
    SELECT
    LA.ACCESS_NO,
    LA.LINEID_FK,
    LA.IP_ADDRESS,
    L.LINEID,
    L.LINENAME
    FROM
    WA_SUA_TBL_ANDON_LA LA,
    WA_GA_TBL_LINES L
    WHERE
    LA.LINEID_FK = L.LINEID
");
oci_execute($qGetAllLine);
while($dGetAllLine = oci_fetch_array($qGetAllLine))
{
    $qPlan = oci_parse($c1, "
        SELECT
        P.PLANID,
        P.LINEID_FK,
        P.RUNNING_DATE,
        P.WIPENTITYID_FK,
        P.UCNO_FK,
        P.RUNNING_QUANTITY,
        TO_CHAR(P.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
        TO_CHAR(P.DATEADDED, 'MI') AS MINUTES,
        TO_CHAR(P.DATEADDED, 'HH24') AS HOURS,
        P.PRODUCTION_STATUS,
        P.PRODUCTION_DURATION,
        P.PROJECTID_FK,
        UC.UC_NO,
        UC.INVENTORYID_FK,
        UC.UPH,
        UC.CAVITY,
        L.LINEID,
        L.LINENAME
        FROM
        WA_SUA_TBL_PLAN P,
        WA_SUA_TBL_UPH_CAVITY UC,
        WA_GA_TBL_LINES L
        WHERE
        P.LINEID_FK = L.LINEID AND
        P.UCNO_FK = UC.UC_NO AND
        P.LINEID_FK = '" . $dGetAllLine['LINEID_FK'] . "' AND
        P.PRODUCTION_STATUS IS NULL AND
        ROWNUM <= 1
        ORDER BY P.RUNNING_DATE DESC
    ");
    oci_execute($qPlan);
    $dPlan = oci_fetch_array($qPlan);

    $lineID[] = $dPlan['LINEID'];

    $planQuantity = $dPlan['RUNNING_QUANTITY'];
    $uph = $dPlan['UPH'];
    $planID = $dPlan['PLANID'];
    $startDateTime = $dPlan['DATEADDEDS'];
    $planMinute = $dPlan['MINUTES'];
    $planHour = $dPlan['HOURS'];

    $getTotalPie = $dPlan['RUNNING_QUANTITY'] / $dPlan['UPH'];

    $getRoundTotalPie = ceil($getTotalPie);

    $dataPie[0] = array('Hour','Quantity');

    for($i=1; $i <=$getRoundTotalPie; $i++)
    {
        $startPlanTime = $planHour.":".$planMinute;

        $continueTime = ($planHour + $i).":".$planMinute;

        $qHourly = oci_parse($c1, "
            SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_HOURLY FROM WA_SUA_TBL_RUNNING_QUANTITY WHERE PLANID_FK = '" . $planID . "' AND DATEADDED BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-08-27 $startPlanTime', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('2019-08-27 $continueTime', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
        ");
        oci_execute($qHourly);
        $dHourly = oci_fetch_array($qHourly);

        $dataPie = array("Hour ".($i), (int)$dHourly['TOTAL_HOURLY']);
    }

    $data[] = array(
        'lineID' => $dGetAllLine['LINEID'],
        'planQuantity' => $planQuantity,
        'dataPie' => $dataPie
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

When tried to run the script, I always got loops even on the empty line.

as you can see below image, for line LN0087 and line LN0088 on dataPie should be not getting value. I suspect on this row maybe `$dataPie = array("Hour ".($i), (int)$dHourly['TOTAL_HOURLY']);`.

Is there any luck how to solve it?

[image]

On red border above image, it should be empty for `dataPie`.

Comment: We have no idea what your actual data looks like here, how do you expect us to be able to answer this? _“as you can see below image, for line LN0087 and line LN0088 on dataPie should be not getting value”_ - no, we can NOT see _why_ those should not get a value, if you only present us a wrong result. Give us a proper _verbal_ explanation why those in particular should not contain this.